# How to make reusable UIView template consisiting UILabels

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, swift

I'm building a weather app as a beginner project. Say I wanted a custom view that consisted on many UILabels for temp, humidity, precipitation, etc. The idea is that this custom UIView would be used several times for every city the user has saved. If the user has 3 cities saved, the custom view would have 3 instances.

What is the best way to do this? I'm trying to subclass a UIView. Originally I was overriding drawRect(rect: CGRect) and defining my UILabels there. That just didn't feel right. And it wouldn't get alloc/inited until way later, after I was trying to update the label text in the completion handler on NSURLSession.

Or should I be overriding init() which makes me do this:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

And I have no idea what that means. Then I'm forced to doing something like this when I try to init with frame on the root VC.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) { super.init(frame: frame) }
```

Can someone walk me through the best approach? I have something like below but I get a nil value right when I'm trying to add the UILabels to subview of the custom class.

```
class ViewTemplate: UIView {

var tempLabel: UILabel!
var humidityLabel: UILabel!

override init () {

tempLabel = UILabel()
tempLabel.frame = CGRectMake(halfScreenWidth - 130, 120, 260, 130)
tempLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
tempLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

// similar stuff for humidityLabel

super.init()        
addSubview(tempLabel)

}

override init(frame: CGRect) { super.init(frame: frame) }

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
 fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

If not quite sure where the nil is coming from. But most importantly, I'm looking for the best practice in doing this.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you building the app with Storyboards or are you doing it programmatically?

Comment: Sounds like you should actually use a table view with prototype cells.

Comment: Hi Adam, I'm building it programmatically.

Comment: the "last word" solution to this sort of thing is the wonderful ...

http://www.paintcodeapp.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.

1. Declare the properties for the labels. It looks like you've already done that. Personally, I would declare those as constants with `let` instead of `var` because you should always have those labels.
2. Override the `init(frame: CGRect)` method. Again, it looks like you've already started this. The reason you should override `init(frame: CGRect)` instead if `init()` is because `init()` just calls `init(frame: CGRectZero)`. If you only implement `init()` then some of your properties may not get initialized (although this is way less of an issue with Swift since you can declare properties as constants so the compiler throws an error). In your initializer you're going to want to init all your labels & set them up right before you call `super.init(frame)`. After the `super.init(frame)` method is called you should add the labels as subviews of self.
3. Override `layoutSubviews()` if you are laying your UI out programmatically. This method is where you will do all the sizing and laying out of your subviews. I do everything this way so it's what I'm most familiar with. If you're using AutoLayout I believe it's best practice to apply those constraints in the class's initializer since they should only ever need to be set up once.
4. Optionally, you may also want to override `sizeThatFits()`. This will ensure your view is always the proper size when `sizeToFit()` is called on it.

This goes not just for `UIView` but any subclass of it.

Comment: There is one strange thing that I'm not quite understanding. If I make an instance of the custom at the property level, and add the view to root VC's subview at viewDidLoad, I can populate my data to the labels (in NSURLSession/ dispatch_async) as expected. But if I make an instance at the property level and add it to the subview within the Completion handler of the NSURLSession, I get nil. I'm actually able to download all of my JSON, populate my model before the instance of my custom UIView inits. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: I experimented a little. I subclassed UIView and left init alone, and didn't override anything. I made a method called say, 'addLabelsToView()', which is where I init and layout the UILabels. I make an instance of this Class in the rootVC. Unlike the issue above, anywhere I add the instance of the custom view, including in the completion block (where I was having trouble before), it completely inits before I populate the labels with data. It seems like overriding init makes it sensitive on when I am actually adding it to the view controller's subview.

Comment: The completion block may not be on the main thread. If you're trying to do something to the UI you have to make sure it's on the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

For creating the individual View:

1. Create new View file. Subclass of UIView. Be sure to also create the xib file when doing this.
2. Draw your items in storyboard (labels, etc.) and connect them to the swift file
3. Be certain that you connect them in storyboard by making the xib file a Custom Class of the swift file you just created.
4. Instantiate them inside the awakeFromNib() method. **Be sure to set their default values for text if they are labels. Otherwise they will come up as nil when instantiated and your app will crash.**

   import UIKit

   class MyView: UIView {

   @IBOutlet weak var templabel: UILabel!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       self.tempLabel.text = "95 degrees"

   }

For loading into viewcontroller:

1a. Create a viewcontroller that implements UIScrollView.
1b. Place a UIScrollview in your storyboard and connect it to that viewcontroller

```
class MyWeatherViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
```

2a. In ViewDidLoad, create instances of the UIView you are looking to create. Populate them individually.
2b. In ViewDidLoad, set the scrollview width to the width of a single View. Set the height to the height of the single View * the number of Views you wish to display

```
       var view1: MyView = MyView()
       var view2: MyView = MyView()
       let viewArray[MyView!] = [view1, view2]

      for items in viewArray {
       var frame = scrollView.bounds

        //Set the origin of the views
        frame.origin.x = 0.0
        frame.origin.y = frame.size.height * items

        //create a view out of the object provided, define it's frame, and add to scrollview
        let viewToAdd = viewArray[items].view
        newPageView.frame = frame
        scrollView.addSubview(viewToAdd)
```

//Set up your labels to be displayed. You must do this AFTER you load the load into the scrollview
           viewArray[items].tempLabel.text = "105 degrees"
       }

Keep in mind that you will want to set up another data model to hold the information that is to be displayed. I would recommend creating an array that holds the information you wish to display, so you can do viewArray[items].tempLabel.text = tempArray[items] with all the labels you wish to set.

This should align them vertically with the ability to scroll and see all items.

This will also let dynamically decide how many views to add based on cities the user has saved. Just modify the logic to read however many cities the user has etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UIViewController extension and initialize a UIView function that takes a UIView. You can use this anywhere in your project.

```
extension UIViewController {
  func setView(_ view: UIView){
     view.backgroundColor = UIColor()
     view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
     // customize your view
  }
}
```

Then: Declare you view in your Controller and pass it when the function is called on viewDidLoad()

```
let myView = UIView()
setView(myView)
```